# Best way for email synchronisation: POP3 UIDL, IMAP UID, message-ID

Tags: imap, pop3, vmime

I'm making a mail client which work POP3 and IMAP. I'm programming the client in C++ with vmime api. My question is: What is the best way for synchronizing mail?

I think that identificator is good way but I don't know what is the best identificator for synchronize mail:

- IMAP: UID  (RFC 3501)
- POP3: UIDL (RFC 1932)
- Internet format message: message-ID (RFC 5322)

message-ID is the easiest to use but is it possible that there are two identical message-ID?
Same question for UID (IMAP) and UIDL (UID)?

can you help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Max is right in saying that a tuple of `(FolderName, UIDVALIDITY, UID)` will never ever refer to any *other* message, there's unfortunately no guarantee that a given message will be always referred to only using that same tuple. Servers are allowed to bump the `UIDVALIDITY`, and there's no standard way of providing unique identifiers which persist across message moves or identify duplicate messages.

Answer (score 3):

In IMAP, the tuple of `(FolderName, UIDVALIDITY, UID)` is guaranteed, by specification, to be forever unique for a given server.  Note that all three values are needed to guarantee uniqueness.  Each folder has it's own UIDs, which may overlap.  A deleted and renamed folder may have the same UIDs as well, but must have different UIDVALIDITYs.

In POP3, UIDL is generally sufficient, since there are no folders.

Message-IDs are generated by the sender, generally, so cannot be guaranteed to be unique.  It's trivial to duplicate this: copy a message from one IMAP folder to another.